# CSVの特定の列に特定の桁の値を抽出するには？

Tags: python, pandas

CSVのファイル、学籍番号の右からの2つ目の数字1の行を抽出したいなら、どうしたらよいですか

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:成績表.csv", index_col= 0 , header = [0],names=cols_name)
df01 = df.drop(['クラス'],axis=1)
df01[["学籍番号"] ==
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

csv_data = '''
学籍番号
B2110
B2111
B2112
B2113
B2114
B2115
B2116
B2117
B2118
B2119
B2120
B2121
B2122
B2123
B2124
B2125
B2126
B2127
B2128
B2129
B2130
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data))

#
df01 = df.query('学籍番号.str[-2] == "1"')
print(df01)

#   学籍番号
# 0    B2110
# 1    B2111
# 2    B2112
# 3    B2113
# 4    B2114
# 5    B2115
# 6    B2116
# 7    B2117
# 8    B2118
# 9    B2119
```